# Where IE stores the cookies?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies

Where IE stores the cookies? Including protected.
If Chrome and FireFoxstored in the database, then IE does not find anything like it.
It is necessary to programmatically create a new cookie. (Console Application)

it not work.

```
 [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lbszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
    private static void SetCookieInternetExplorer(string value)
    {
        string pathCookie = "Path=/cas/";
        string secureCookie = "Secure=true";
        InternetSetCookie(casHost, casCookieName, value);
        InternetSetCookie(casHost, casCookieName, pathCookie);
        InternetSetCookie(casHost, casCookieName, secureCookie);

[DllImport("ieframe.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool IESetProtectedModeCookie(string url, string name, string data, int flags);

public static bool SetWinINETCookieString()
{
  IESetProtectedModeCookie("http://url.co.uk", "name", "data=blah; expires = Sat,01-Jan-2012 00:00:00 GMT; path=/", 0x10);
  IESetProtectedModeCookie("http://url.co.uk", "name", "data=blah; expires = Sat,01-Jan-2012 00:00:00 GMT; path=/", 0);

 return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this but take a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7539628/1814840).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a cookie outside of a web-browser (E.g., With VBScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530734/creating-a-cookie-outside-of-a-web-browser-e-g-with-vbscript)

Comment: @RichardEverett not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InternetSetCookie works.
You should always specify the protocol.
The name must be null.
The date must be valid (day of week).
Then everything works.